# How to recover corrupted btrfs partition that nothing can read

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, btrfs, filesystem-corruption

I was on Manjaro on a btrfs partition. I came back to my laptop and it wasn't accepting my password, which in the past I solved with a reboot. I tried to reboot from tty 2 which was logged in, and it failed, ending with something like "froze execution" from systemd. So I forced a shutdown, hoping that if there was a corruption issue I could use the btrfs tools to fix it or recover it.
(As for why that happened, it's possible that there was a physical connection issue since the system drive is connected via USB. It's my only option right now.)

GRUB gave "unknown filesystem". I tried booting into Kubuntu, it would also not recognize the btrfs. From another answer I wrote the magic `_BHRfS_M` which let the system recognize that it's btrfs and show it in file manager but it doesn't mount and nothing else was fixed. I tried using the btrfs-progs tools which worked for me with another drive before. I tried `btrfs check /dev/sdb2`, `btrfs check --rescue /dev/sdb2`, all the ones under `btrfs rescue`, `btrfs restore`, and `btrfs scrub`. All the commands give me the error `No valid Btrfs found on /dev/sdb2`, except chunk-recover which gives

```
read super block error
recover prepare error
Chunk tree recovery failed
```

Using cat and grep, I looked for some code and I see that the content of the files is intact in the drive, including multiple backups. I don't get why this is happening- how can it be that all of the recovery tools immediately fail like this and I can't get any result from it? Is there any hope to recover at least parts of the filesystem?

Comment: That's a lot of views this has gotten. My advice to anyone reading: do not use btrfs if you're not sure your drive connection and power will be completely smooth. It's a shame because it has really good features, but it's prone to get some horrible corruption very easily like what happened here. I lost a bunch of code, I lost the project for the first song I released.. ext4, on the other hand, has always been perfectly reliable for me even in really unstable situations. My power goes out often, but with ext4 it has never cost me anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have a recent backup to restore: I would dd image the entire drive now, and work on a copy of that image. (If it's hardware failing, then you don't want to be thrashing it.)

fsck.btrfs would be the first thing I would throw at it.

If that failed then testdisk, to restore the partition table. Then see if it will mount and read as normal.

If that failed then the scalpel or photorec to try and recover individual intact (or not) files.

Once/if you recover the data, check drive smart data. If it's OK then give it a destructive badblocks run. Then restore your data to it.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think it's hardware failing since the SSD is only a few months old and accidentally disconnecting drives (in this case the USB cable may not be the most reliable) mid use has led me to this type of issue. fsck.btrfs just tells me to use btrfs check. Photorec works right away, though it's not optimal.

Comment: From the [man page](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fsck.btrfs.html), "Traditional filesystems need to run their respective `fsck` utility in case the filesystem was not unmounted cleanly and the log needs to be replayed before mount. **This is not needed for BTRFS.** ... If you wish to check the consistency of a BTRFS filesystem or repair a damaged filesystem, see `btrfs-check`(8)."